# Where are Go templates allowed in docker-compose files?

Tags: docker-compose, go-templates

The title is self explanatory: I wasn't able to find a document describing where Go templates are allowed in compose files.

In other words I wish to know which of the following is supported:

```
version: "3.7"


services:
  whoami:
    image: "containous/whoami"
    environment:
      - VALUE='{{.Name}}'
      - NAME_{{.Name}}='NAME'
    deploy:
      labels:
        - value={{.Name}}
        - name_{{.Name}}=NAME
    networks:
      - {{.Name}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I kept searching and apparently the information is actually provided in the [official Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#create-services-using-templates), even if it doesn't explicitly refer to the docker compose file format.

In particular:

> You can use templates for some flags of service create, using the
>   syntax provided by the Go’s text/template package.
>
> The supported flags are the following :
>
> --hostname
>   --mount
>   --env

As `--labels` is not listed we should assume text/template replacement is not allowed in there.

Comment: That would have been too good to be true. I just declared `hostname: "{{.Service.Name}}"` in a `docker-compose.yml` file to verify this. `docker-compose exec <service-name> cat /etc/hostname` just yielded `{{.Service.Name}}`. So no, sadly this does not work, at least not for `--hostname`.

Comment: I would try using single quotes rather than double...

Comment: Gave it a quick test and that did _not_ work either. It's simply and sadly not supported.

Comment: Maybe this is a newer feature, but as of today, Go template syntax is working for service hostnames, environment variables and also network/volume names! So you can create a host specific volume for a service and also a specific volumes for multiple replicas of a services: `name: '{{.Node.Hostname}}-myservice-{{.Task.Slot}}-data'`

Comment: @krassdanke this keeps coming back every now and then: I was looking to use templating in labels, not env variables, hostnames or volumes, which were all supported back then in 2019.
Weird none seems to see I was looking for labels...

Answer (score 1):

Go templates are a part of the Go standard library. `docker-compose` is a separate application as part of `docker`.

**1. Declare your template.**

You can declare your template as a `const` within your `Go` code, or have it in a file.

```
const composeTemplate = `version: "3.7"

services:
  whoami:
    image: "containous/whoami"
    environment:
      - VALUE='{{.Name}}'
      - NAME_{{.Name}}='NAME'
    deploy:
      labels:
        - value={{.Name}}
        - name_{{.Name}}=NAME
    networks:
      - {{.Name}}
`
```

**2. Config for your template.**

Create a configuration type that will be populated and used to execute the template.

```
type Config struct {
    Name string
}
```

**3. Execute your template with config.**

```
conf := &Config{Name: "MyService"}

tpl, err := template.New("myservice").Parse(composeTemplate)
if err != nil {
    // Handle error.
}

var output bytes.Buffer
err = tpl.Execute(&output, conf)
if err != nil {
    // Handle error.
}
```

**4. Write your output to a file.**

```
err = ioutil.WriteFile("myservice-compose.yml", output.Bytes(), 0644)
if err != nil {
    // Handle error.
}
```

[(Go Playground)](https://play.golang.com/p/RXomOr_n_Mq)

Good luck!

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear, but as docker is written in Golang, it is possible to use Golang templates to perform actions directly in docker, as an example it is possible to tell docker to set an environment variable with the evaluated go template, like in `docker service create --name rlogiacco --env SERVICE_NAME="{{.Service.Name}}" alpine /bin/sh -c 'echo service is $SERVICE_NAME check'`. So I am asking where those templates are allowed in relation to the docker compose file format

Answer (score 0):

I am curious about "where is documentation?" on this, but yes, it is almost working. `docker-compose` is another application that parse a yaml file to feed docker client interface to send command to docker daemon, or at least this is what I understood, because it looks like the golang templates pass through and are replaced.

Here is an example of use
https://github.com/lovelysystems/rabbitmq-swarm-cluster/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

More on this:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37377

I think open a new case is a good idea, but who maintain docker.com docs?

Comment: In my self answer I reported it does work for environment, mount and hostname, but I need it on labels, which is not supported. I’ve also reported the location for such documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you need is possible, at least according to `compose` docs. Please note that `docker-compose` is written in python and it uses `docker` APIs.

If your need is defining some [variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) inside `docker-compose.yaml` file, then you can do that using `${SOME_VAR}` syntax.

Var values may be stored in `.env` file which you can reference in your `compose` commands using `docker compose --env-file [path_to_env_file]` syntax

See sample repository using the above on [GitHub](https://github.com/w7089/selenium_tests_in_docker)